# Java phrase guessing game

Tags: java

Wondering how to exit if total phrase is guessed and why my vowels, spaces and consonants are not counting? Most of progam runs great just cant figure out how to exit without saying "n" to question. I am returning values for counters, don't understand?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Prog09 
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Initializes all string variables
    String sPhrase;
    String answer;

    // Initializes all int variables
    int vowels = 0;
    int consonants = 0;
    int spaces = 0;

    // Initializes all char variables
    char cGuess = 0;
    char vGuess = 0;

    boolean valid = false;

    // Asks user to enter if they want to play
    System.out.print("Do you want to play a game? [y/n] ");
    answer = stdIn.nextLine();

    // Asks user to enter the phrase
    System.out.print("Please enter the phrase to guess at : ");
    sPhrase = stdIn.nextLine();

    // Checks if user wants to play
    while (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
    {
        char[] phrase = new char[sPhrase.length()]; 
        char[] tmpArr = new char[sPhrase.length()];
        for(int i = 0; i < sPhrase.length();i++)
        {
            tmpArr[i] = sPhrase.charAt(i);
            phrase[i] = sPhrase.charAt(i);
        }

        // Runs methods and main body of program
        initTemplateArray(sPhrase, tmpArr, spaces);

        printHeader();
        printTemplateArray(tmpArr);
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");

        while (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
        {
            //getConsonant(stdIn, cGuess);
            cGuess = getConsonant(stdIn, cGuess);

            vGuess = getVowel(stdIn, vGuess);

            isVowel(vGuess, valid);

            updateTemplateArray(tmpArr, sPhrase, cGuess, vGuess, consonants, vowels);

            printHeader();
            printTemplateArray(tmpArr);
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("");

            stdIn.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Do you want to try again? [y/n]: ");
            answer = stdIn.next();

            vGuess = 0;
            cGuess = 0;

        }
    }

    // Prints results
    System.out.println("The common phrase contained: Spaces: " + spaces + " Consonants: " + consonants + " Vowels: " + vowels);

    stdIn.close();
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


// Methods for program
public static int initTemplateArray(String sPhrase, char [] tmpArr, int spaces)
{   
    for (int i = 0; i < sPhrase.length(); i++)
    {
        if (sPhrase.charAt(i) == ' ')
        {
            spaces++;
            tmpArr[i] = ' ';
        }

        if (!(sPhrase.charAt(i) == ' '))
        {
            tmpArr[i] = '?';
        }
    }

    return spaces;
}

public static void printTemplateArray(char [] tmpArr)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < tmpArr.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.print(tmpArr[i]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}

public static boolean isVowel(char c, boolean valid)
{
    if(c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c == 'u')
        {
            return valid = true;
        }
    else
        {
            return valid = false;
        }
}

public static char getConsonant(Scanner stdIn, char cGuess)
{   
    while(cGuess == 'a' || cGuess == 'e' || cGuess == 'i' || cGuess == 'o' || cGuess == 'u'|| cGuess == 0)
    {
        System.out.print("Enter a lowercase consonant guess : ");
        String myGuess = stdIn.next();
        cGuess = myGuess.charAt(0);
    }

    return cGuess;
}

public static char getVowel(Scanner stdIn, char vGuess)
{
    while(!(vGuess == 'a' || vGuess == 'e' || vGuess == 'i' || vGuess == 'o' || vGuess == 'u'))
    {
        System.out.print("Enter a lowercase vowel guess : ");
        String newGuess = stdIn.next();
        vGuess = newGuess.charAt(0);
    }

    return vGuess;
}

public static int updateTemplateArray(char [] tmpArr, String sPhrase, char cGuess, char vGuess, int consonants, int vowels)
{
    vowels = 0;
    consonants = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < tmpArr.length; i++)
    {
        if (cGuess == sPhrase.charAt(i))
        {
            tmpArr[i] = sPhrase.charAt(i);
            consonants++;
        }

        if (vGuess == sPhrase.charAt(i))
        {
            tmpArr[i] = sPhrase.charAt(i);
            vowels++;
        }
    }
    return consonants & vowels;
}

public static void printHeader()
{
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println(" Common Phrase");
    System.out.println("---------------");
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java passes Ints by value instead of by reference, this means that updateTemplateArray doesn't modify the values of main's vowels, consonants or spaces.  To fix this you could:

Make these variables global by definining them outside the scope of the main method.  You would have to change the name of the parameters in the updateTemplateArray method to prevent shadowing.

Break updateTemplateArray into separate functions to count each of the vowels, consonants or spaces, and have them return the count of each.  You would then call something like: vowels = countVowels(sPhrase); to populate the variables.

With the current setup, it will exit whenever answer stops being equal to 'y'   Changing the value of answer at any time will exit the loop.

Comment: still need a way if they guess complete phrase it will also exit?

Comment: you would just need to change the value of answer to something other than y.  It will exit both loops.  If you want to exit the inner but no the outer, then you need to change the inner loop's while statement to some other variable, and change that variable.

Comment: is there a way to write it so that when sPhrase = tmpArr it exits, or something around those lines?

Comment: While (!(sPhrase.equals(tmpArr))  So, while sPhrase isn't equal to tmpArr, run the loop

Comment: tried it out and still will only exit if you say "n". any ideas?

Comment: work throuhg what the logic does, and modify it.  This is not a super difficult thing, and you should be able to figure it out if you work throguh it